# How to Mock NamedPipeClientStream

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I created a class called MpvController to handle communication protocols over a .NET NamedPipeClientStream.

Now, I need to test this controller. I have a second class named MpvControllerFactory that creates the controllers.

I moved the code to establish the connection from MpvController to MpvControllerFactory, so that MpvController receives only a Stream that can be replaced with a MemoryStream.

But now, the problem is that NamedPipeClientStream doesn't behave like a standard stream. NamedPipeClientStream has neither Length nor Position. It has 2 separate buffers for Input and Output.

A MemoryStream, on the other hand, when you write to it, it moves the position to the end so there's nothing left to read. It's a continuous shared buffer for both input and output.

So then, how can I mock the behaviors of NamedPipeClientStream?

It will be important to mock to be able to test asynchronous and multi-threaded behaviors.

Comment: Do you mean this community deals purely with theories and practical uses are forbidden? In the past I found this community to be better with anything related to unit testing and code design.

Comment: Coding help is explicitly off-topic here, to distinguish the site from Stackoverflow. How far that goes is surely opinionated and surely seen different by different people in our community. But if you found a solution, I recommend not to add it to the question text, but post it as an answer to your own question, that would a way better of using the Q&A format of this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer. PipeStream behaves differently than normal streams, so the Controller must take in a PipeStream or NamedPipeClientStream to avoid confusion.

Initializing the connection in the factory is the right way to go.

Then all I need to do for testing is to create a NamedPipeServerStream to interact with the NamedPipeClientStream.

It's important to read the stream that's being written to, and it's important to enable Asynchronous option.

Here's the solution I came up with

```
private const string PipeName = "testpipe";
[NotNull]
private NamedPipeServerStream? _server;
[NotNull]
private NamedPipeClientStream? _client;
private byte[] _readBuffer = new byte[1];
[NotNull]
private IMpvControllerBase? _model;

private void InitConnection()
{
    _server = new NamedPipeServerStream(PipeName, PipeDirection.InOut, NamedPipeServerStream.MaxAllowedServerInstances,
                                            PipeTransmissionMode.Byte,
                                            PipeOptions.Asynchronous);
    _client = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", PipeName, PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);
    _client.Connect();
    _server.WaitForConnection();
    BeginReadLoop();
    _model = new MpvControllerBase(_client);
}

private void BeginReadLoop()
{
    _server!.BeginRead(_readBuffer, 0, 1, DataReceived, null);
}

private void DataReceived(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    if (_server.EndRead(ar) > 0)
    {
        BeginReadLoop();
    }
}
```

**Note: This is not the proper way of listening to the pipe.**

You'll eventually need to dispose your class and stop listening. There is no CancellationToken allowing you to stop the listen loop. I ended up writing a PipeStreamListener class with a StartAsync method that doesn't return until the loop stops, and doing the loop with ReadAsync and a CancellationToken. Making sure PipeStreamListener is disposable. However, this is beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would question here is the necessity to mock out `NamedPipeClientStream` at all. If there are two components A and B where A depends on B, the reasons why B is mocked out in an automated test for A are usually:

1. B is complex, and in case of an error, you want to make sure a failing test for A really shows in error A and not in B
2. Using B in a test makes the tests for A too slow.

Here, B is `NamedPipeClientStream` which is a .Net framework component, which can be assumed to be well-tested enough that 1 is most probably not relevant. Moreover,  AFAIK `NamedPipeClientStream` is an in-memory mechanism for interprocess communication, so it may not be as fast as an in-process `MemoryStream`, but it could be actually fast enough for most real-world tests.

If `NamedPipeClientStream` turns out to be indeed not fast enough for your tests, you can use the standard approach for mocking: create an interface `IMyPipeClientStream`, derive an class `MyPipeClientStream` from it which is implemented as an adapter to `NamedPipeClientStream`, and create another derivation `MockPipeClientStream` which provides a in-memory mock for the same interface.

Comment: Essentially, what you're saying is to still use NamedPipeClientStream instead of MemoryStream for the tests. The connecting being established in the Factory, my design allows me to swap the stream, so I just have to mimic a server connection. That should work. Since NamedPipeClientStream behaves differently than Stream, MpvController class should expect a PipeStream to avoid confusion -- just that it should already be initialized.